# Is there a way each time i submit android project to bitbucket a apk to be sent to Hokeyapp

Tags: android, bitbucket

So i have a android project which is in Bitbucket. I also have a HokeyApp for my project. Each time I submit in bitbucket, I have to create the apk and upload it to hokeyapp. Is there a way for me to make it so that each time I submit in bitbucket the apk is build and sent to hokeyapp? If some one knows a solution that includes a alternative to hokeyapp it is also ok i am willing to use it.

Comment: You will need to use Jenkin which will run when any new code is pushed to git and it will create the apk and publish it on Hockey. Use this link for more->> https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HockeyApp+Plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to make it but i did it. I made a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ivan.dimitrov.work/integrate-hokeyapp-with-bitbucket-for-android-project-d7f3751b2bb4) how to do it hope it helps some one.